# How to show drop down width in the overflow hidden?

Tags: html, css, overflow, z-index, bxslider

Is there any solution to show dropdown when using overflow in bxslider ?

actually the div has `overflow:hidden` to show carousel properly. Does anybody have idea to fix this issue with z

[image]

```
.member{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50%;

    width: 150px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: -75px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZpzPG/

Comment: Are you referring to overflow:hidden?

Comment: @bboymaanu It's not entirely clear what it is you are trying to do. Could you edit your question to explain?

Comment: @Blake plugin has `overflow:hidden` to hide rest of the thumbnails. At the same time I need to show thumbnail details when **mouseover** or **click** which not possible now :(

Comment: @Paulie_D Could you please check updated question. Hope the image can give a proper idea about the question.

Comment: You have a class bx-viewport which has as one of its rules overflow:hidden. If you remove that - you'll be able to see the complete red box

Comment: @Danield Rest of the thumbnails are showing when remove `overflow:hidden`from `bx-viewport` :(

Comment: @scooterlord I have created unique `div` and put the list out side of the `overflow:hidden`. You can see live version here at **http://www.digimobgroup.com/** let me know if you have any query

Comment: Where exactly is it? I need the dropdown menu to be inside one of the slides. So, I guess you worked around it and haven't solved the particular problem..

Comment: @scooterlord You can see one the page at **THE TEAM BEHIND** section. I haven't found an exact solution for the issue because we are using `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: @Athimannil I have same problem. Did you fined any solution  ?

Comment: @innovation Sorry bit busy now, It has been fixed(1 year ago) with some alternative solution. However I will send you that solution after work

Comment: @Athimannil Thanks for your respond my friend. I am waiting your solution. This is my problem question [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607492/overflow-hidden-position-within-the-absolute-div-z-index)

Comment: @Athimannil please don't forget aswer me dear.

Comment: @innovation I am making the solution as demo unfortunately I forgot most the things. Here is the website I have done the solution http://www.digimobgroup.com/ (go to team behind part)

Comment: @innovation I will add demo when made jsfiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63813/discussion-between-athimannil-and-innovation).

Comment: @innovation the answer might be helpful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any possibility to show child elements to show outside of the parent `overflow:hidden`

```js
$('#members-bio').bxSlider({
  slideWidth: 300,
  minSlides: 2,
  maxSlides: 2,
  slideMargin: 10
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('figure').click(function() {
    var memberDetails = $(".member-details"),
      item = $(this),
      listLeft = (item.offset().left) + 60;
    memberDetails.offset({
      left: listLeft
    }).addClass('active-member');
  });
});
```

```css
figure {
  margin: 0;
}
.member {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: -75px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.member-details {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
.active-member {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<div id="members-div">
  <ul id="members-bio">
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=memerb1">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=memerb2">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=memerb3">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=memerb4">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=memerb5">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=memerb6">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=memerb7">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=memerb8">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=memerb9">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=memerb10">
      </figure>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="member-details">
    <p>Yes here</p>
    <p>is the</p>
    <p>member details</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

im not quite sure what you mean here? never heard of the overlap: hidden, ive heard of overflow, but the issue is u want to show the entire .member class without getting it cut off by the slider ?

In that case, take the "top" Atribute off and then in your html put you div.member over the image and it will place it self so u can see all the data?