# css overflow hidden does not conform to the rules of z-index

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I have one problem about div positions.

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/ebaac7db41ba92d193a55a9423ac3765)**. If you click the demo you can see there are 3 image. When you mause hover over the image then bubble div will open. but it is not shows me outside.

```
.bubble 
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 345px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: #d8dbdf solid 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(216, 219, 223, 0.52);
    -moz-box-shadow:    -1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(216, 219, 223, 0.52);
    box-shadow:         -1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(216, 219, 223, 0.52);
    display:none;
    margin-left:-345px;
}

.bubble:after 
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    border-color: transparent #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    right: -10px;
    top: 16px;
}
```

Comment: It's working for me on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/9r5wh2gL/
Or what do you mean "outside"?

Comment: How it work from `jsfiddle` ? It is not working `codepen.io`

Comment: what do you want to achive? when i hover the first image, the whole bubble appears to me at the left of the 1st image.

Comment: anyway, what if you set the widht of the container more than 305px?

Comment: It is looks like this : [IMAGE](https://scontent-a-ams.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-9/1010419_933797079981931_8183454203056861307_n.jpg?oh=7b8ebe19f28cda8f0f0f908d83a91581&oe=54F7A009)

Comment: @lolka_bolka you are not added a jquery from your jsfiddle please add jquery then tell me it is working or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63783/discussion-between-innovation-and-lolka-bolka).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that overflow hidden does not conform to the rules of Z-index. ANYTHING outside of the box that is hidden is assumed to be outside of the document. You need to find a way that satisfies your ability to do that.

Child element can't show out side of the parent `overflow:hidden`

```js
$('#members-bio').bxSlider({
  slideWidth: 300,
  minSlides: 2,
  maxSlides: 2,
  slideMargin: 10
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('figure').click(function() {
    var memberDetails = $(".member-details"),
      item = $(this),
      listLeft = (item.offset().left) + 60;
    memberDetails.offset({
      left: listLeft
    }).addClass('active-member');
  });
});
```

```css
figure {
  margin: 0;
}
.member {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: -75px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.member-details {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
.active-member {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="members-div">
  <ul id="members-bio">
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=product">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=product">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=product">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=product">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=product">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=product">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=product">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=product">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=product">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=product">
      </figure>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="member-details">
    <p>Product name</p>
    <p>Product details</p>
    <p>buy now</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your bubble must be placed outside the block with "overflow: hidden" and be positioned relative image. 
Block with class="sinevis" have style="overflow: hidden;" and it just cut off your bubble.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow hidden actually is your problem... You need to set the items that you want to display on hover OUTSIDE of your element that is overflow hidden.

Problem is that overflow hidden does not conform to the rules of Z-index. ANYTHING outside of the box that is hidden is assumed to be outside of the document. You need to find a way that satisfies your ability to do that.

Sadly you have a lot of divs to go through so I am not 100% willing to show you exactly how I would do it, but it is a simple concept. If you set essentially a element as display none outside of the box and give it an id use a replace of html in it and then use offset of mouse you can do it 100% no problems. The element would then bout outside of the overflow box and you'll be able to see it above it.

Comment: Could not do? As in you could not place an element outside of the box?

Comment: I am using `overflow:hidden;` this `overflow:hidden;` coming from my jquery code. It is not allow me your solution.

Comment: blows my mind... All I have to say it has to be the plugin / code you're using in your jquery. There is no reason I should be limited as much as I am, but for a variety of things I see you are not going to have an easy time replicating it. I would say scrap what ever that code is for the jquery slider and write your own. It would probably be way better any way and you can most likely do more with it. If you wrote it you need to seriously rethink how you wrote it, but it is really constricting. It is returning false on hover which is why you can't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

Put that hover container outside the box with overflow. With :first-child,:last-child in css You will know on what element mouse is over so ,U will be able to add apropriate box position.